# Need a %sale for Sql or c# for SQL please

Tags: c#, sql

I am stuck, need to write a code for a c# application, connected with Sql, and need a query to lower the price by 20% if the validity time is on half, and by 50% if it is on 0.25 since the expiration date.
Could you please help me...
Also,
My Sql DB is called Market
The table i need is New
And the date row is validity

Thanks again...

Comment: _"a query to lower the price by 20% if the validity time is on half, and by 50% if it is on 0.25 since the expiration date."_ can you please elaborate on these requirements? What does your schema look like? Why do want the DB to make these calculations. It's business logic after all. If you ever wanted to modify this, you'd have to adjust the sql statements. Code is easier to test.

Comment: can you be more specific, the statement is very generic and its is up to you where you want to write the logic. in this case better to do it on sql to get exact data. but really situational.

Comment: I need this query in the SSMS, then execute it in a C# Windows form application...

Comment: ALTER TABLE [TableName] ADD [ExpireRate] AS DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETDATE(), ExpiredAt) / DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreatedAt, ExpiredAt)

GO
UPDATE [TableName] SET Price = Price * CASE WHEN ExpireRate < 0.25 THEN 0.5 WHEN ExpireRate < 0.5 THEN 0.2 ELSE 1 END

Comment: You may want to put some code which you wrote and ask more specific questions on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the below query based on the columns.

```
SELECT  
  CASE
    WHEN ValidityDate > '2021-05-30' THEN  (price *0.75)
    WHEN ValidityDate > '2021-06-15' THEN  (price *0.50)
    ELSE price
  END AS NewPrice
FROM NewPrices
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with computed field.

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] ADD [PriceByExpire] AS CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETDATE(), ExpiredAt) / DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreatedAt, ExpiredAt) < 0.25 THEN 1.5 * Price 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETDATE(), ExpiredAt) / DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreatedAt, ExpiredAt) < 0.5 THEN 1.2 * Price 
ELSE Price END
```